# Power bi How can i display items without data with a zero AND hide the months in the future

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I'm using the following measure in order to make the charts display the periods that don't have a value. But the problem now is that it is displaying the months in the future.

```
x Count Tickets = 
            IF
                (
                    ISBLANK
                        (
                            DISTINCTCOUNT('Tickets DB'[Número de Ticket])
                        )
                    ,0,
                    DISTINCTCOUNT('Tickets DB'[Número de Ticket])
                )
```

[image]

How can I avoid the months in the future from displaying?

I also tried the following measure:

```
x Count Tickets = 
IF
    (
        DATEDIFF(MAX('Tickets DB'[Fecha]),TODAY(),DAY)>0,
                        IF
                            (
                            ISBLANK
                                (
                                    DISTINCTCOUNT('Tickets DB'[Número de Ticket])
                                )
                            ,0,
                            DISTINCTCOUNT('Tickets DB'[Número de Ticket])
                            )
    )
```

But it is not displaying months without data

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the solution would be: create a "DATES TABLE"  with all possible values between the minimum date until today.

Then another table "TICKET COUNTS" with the tickets per day and client. Join both together: "DATES TABLE" with "COUNTS TABLE".

This way the days without tickets will have a value of null that could be switched to zero.

Then create the chart using the joined table. I just can't figure out how to join the dates table to the counts' table, and still, don't know how to put that together in DAX. In SQL is so easy.

Comment: You're calendar table should'nt have dates in the future.

Comment: Indeed StelioK. That’s why I will delimit between the first date and today.

Answer (score 2):

```
IF (
    MAX ( 'DimDate'[Date] ) > TODAY (),
    BLANK (),
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Tickets DB'[Número de Ticket] ) + 0
)
```

Starting from your original measure, we check whether the date in context is after today's date. In that case, we blank the measure. Otherwise we do your `DISTINCTCOUNT`, which may possibly return a blank value. Note that DAX blanks are not equivalent to SQL NULLs - specifically addition with a blank returns a number, unless both addends are blank; so `BLANK () + 0 = 0`. This neatly solves your display for months with no data. But we only execute this logic for past months.

Note, I've written this assuming that you have a date table. If you don't, you should get one. I like [mine](https://github.com/baldiniunlimited/daxdates), but there are plenty of good ones out there.

Answer (score 1):

**1**. First create a calculated column(calendar dimension table), to return if there is a record on all dates of this dimension

[example of calculated column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1ck0.png)

**2.** 
Create the measurement below (
Where you will change the context of the measurement to bring only the true fields from the column you created earlier)

```
   Medida Stack = 
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(
            fVendas[CLIENTE/LOJA]);
            CALCULATETABLE(
                dCalendario;
                dCalendario[Has Sales?]=TRUE()
            )
    )
```

*fvendas[Cliente/loja] = 'Tickets DB'[Número de Ticket]
dCalendario = calendar dimension table*

Comment: Doesn't work. It won't display the items without data (i.e. february and may)

Comment: change the calculated column syntax (in the calendar dimension table) to:

if(dCalendario[Data]>today();FALSE();TRUE())

Comment: Thanks, Marcelo. Still, the dates without tickets won't display data, and if I add "is null" then the chart will display the months in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If it is always the dates in the future you want to hide, you could opt for relative date filtering on your visual. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/desktop-slicer-filter-date-range)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. You have to try the measure in the question and check it out.

Comment: Your date should be independent of that measure. Also a simplified version for it is ```x Count Tickets = DISTINCTCOUNT('Tickets DB'[Número de Ticket]) + 0``` Can you share a Power BI sample?

Comment: Adding the "+ 0 " will make the future months appear. I will try to make the sample file. Note that I am using the date hierarchy. I think when going from year to month is causing this. Thank you.

Comment: Drag the date hierarchy directly to the filter pane. You'll get an extra block in addition to filters for month year quarter and day, that allow you to filter on full date.

Answer (score 1):

Create a calendar table using something like the following:

```
Calendar = 
VAR MinDate = MIN('Tickets DB'[Fecha])
VAR MaxDate = MAX('Tickets DB'[Fecha])
VAR BaseCalendar =
    CALENDAR ( MinDate, MaxDate )
RETURN
    GENERATE (
        BaseCalendar,
        VAR Basedate = [Date]
        VAR YearDate =
            YEAR ( Basedate )
        VAR MonthNumber =
            MONTH ( Basedate )
        VAR YrMonth = 100 * YearDate + MonthNumber
        VAR Qtr =
            CONCATENATE ( "Q", CEILING ( MONTH ( Basedate ) / 3, 1 ) )
        VAR QtrYr = YearDate & " " & Qtr
        RETURN
            ROW (
                "Day", Basedate,
                "Year", YearDate,
                "Month Number", MonthNumber,
                "Month", FORMAT ( Basedate, "mmmm" ),
                "Year Month", FORMAT ( Basedate, "mmm yy" ),
                "YrMonth", YrMonth,
                "Qtr", Qtr,
                "QtrYr", QtrYr
            )
    )
```

If you have dates in the future in your table, replace the `MAX('Tickets DB'[Fecha])` part to `NOW()` then just create a relationship from your 'Tickets DB' table to this calendar table on both date fields and that should correct the issue (and allow you to use time intelligence functions). Once this is set up correctly your measure should work just fine.

Hope it helps.